# Cocoa empty loop failure

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Still a Cocoa rookie,

I have this loop executing in the background thread of my application:

```
while (preProcessed == FALSE){}
```

This hogs the thread for a second or two while a main-thread task completes (involving a webview - hence main thread required).

It was working perfectly, the app was submitted to Apple, all good.

Now, suddenly - it has stopped working. The loop either never exits or never starts, basically the application just silently hangs at this point.

Even if I add an arbitrary action, such as

```
int idle_hands_etc = 0;
while (preProcessed == FALSE){ ++idle_hands_etc;}
```

Nothing happens..

However, if I print something to the Output console:

```
while (preProcessed == FALSE){ printf(".");}
```

It works perfectly.

My question is, what the hell is going on! And secondly, what has changed to make this behave differently, because it certainly wasn't my application.

Comment: I suspect the compiler has recognised that those statements *don't do anything* and has optimized them out.

Comment: are you sure, you havent redefined FALSE or preProcessed ?

Answer (score 1):

These statements:

```
int idle_hands_etc = 0;
while (preProcessed == FALSE){ ++idle_hands_etc;}
```

Don't actually do anything as nothing reads from `idle_hands_etc`, so the compiler has optimized them out.  This will occur during the *Release* build of your app, and not during the *Debug* build, when optimization is turned off.

Another possibility is that `preProcessed` has not be declared with the `volatile` qualifier, which might be required for the compiler to consider it mutable.

This type of wait loop is inefficient anyway and you need to investigate multi-threading synchronization mechanisms that allow the thread to *sleep* while it's not working and allow it to be woken up when the task it's waiting for completes.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have this loop executing in the background thread of my application:

while (preProcessed == FALSE){}
This hogs the thread for a second or two while a main-thread task completes (involving a webview - hence main thread required).
```

No need to use a dummy loop to eat some seconds, you can direct the control to wait until current task is not processed. You can opt for following method, with YES as waitUntilDone

```
performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

Comment: The preprocess flag is set by a [webView didReceiveTitle] so waitUntilDone can't identify when the title has been received. Basically, I'm parsing some HTML with javascript using the WebView rendering engine. The last thing that the javascript does is set the page title to "Complete" - The didRecieveTitle identifies this, sets the flag, and returns to the background thread to save the formatted HTML.